# why class 'Agama' not found? (related to Yii2Framework)

Tags: php, yii2

when I try to display related data in views i wrote this code
the directory of this code ".../frontend/views/biodataorang/_form.php

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;
use yii\db\ActiveQuery

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $model app\models\Biodataorang */
/* @var $form yii\widgets\ActiveForm */
?>

<div class="biodataorang-form">

    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'ID')->textInput() ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'AgamaID')->textInput() ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'StatusKawinID')->textInput() ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'PekerjaanID')->textInput() ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'SukuBangsaID')->textInput() ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'WargaNegaraID')->textInput() ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'GolonganDarahID')->textInput() ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'Tinggi')->textInput() ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'Berat')->textInput() ?>

    <?php
        echo $form->field($model, 'AgamaID')->dropDownList(ArrayHelper::map(Agama::find()->select(['nama','id'])->all(), 'id', 'displayName'),['class' => 'form-control inline-block']);
    ?>

    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? Yii::t('app', 'Create') : Yii::t('app', 'Update'), ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
    </div>

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

</div>
```

but when i try to update the table with create 'biodataorang' as examples (I have used gii), there was something error and it said class 'Agama' not found.

what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `use` construct for this class.

Add among the others at the top one more use like:

```
use [...]\Agama;
```

You need to check what is the proper namespace for this class to use instead [...] there. It might be

```
use app\models\Agama;
```

based on the other model that is used here.

[Read more about namespaces and using them](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php).